# Highlighting of a makefile in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile

I have two makefiles in Eclipse, one is named `all.mak` and the second is called Makefile.

My Problem is that Makefile is highlighted correctly when opend with the Makefile-Editor but alle.mak is not.
I know that under Window→Preferences→General→Editors→File Associations one can set the Makefile-Editor to open this file and I did so (but no highlighting for `all.mak`).

Is there another preference I have to make for correct highlighting of the `all.mak`-File?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is another preference to set. Go to..

1. Open the preferences view:  Window → Preferences
2. General (in left panel)
3. Content Types
4. In the right panel ("Content types"): Text
5. Makefile

Press the 'Add' button, and enter the same filename as you did in the File Association view.